# Should I be developing for Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'd like to install it on my development machine for when it comes out.  But I'm afraid projects in between won't be right, and applications will be cumbersome to test.  I am using VWD 2008 Express.  Also not sure whether or not to use an RC1.

Thanks.

edit:

This is for an Intranet which I know will only have IE.  Thank you again.

Comment: This question should be migrated to retro computing :-p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should **never** be developing **for** a browser, but you should be testing **with** it. Internet Explorer 8 is in release candidate status, which means that the final release will render consistently (barring any glaring errors).

Comment: yes, although those that test it regularly will tell you it does have many glaring errors, regressions and rendering quirks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think you should start including IE 8 into your testing as there are some notable differences to previous rendering engines.

However, I would recommend that you install any browser that is under development (or those that are not part of your core testing) on a virtual machine.

As a side, you should also include Chrome into your testing as it is gaining significant adoption.

Answer (score 2):

You could use virtual machine to to this.You can use VirtualPC or VMWare or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the audience you want to reach.

If your audience are early adopter types, and are likely to use IE8, then Yes - you should be developing with that in mind.

You may also want to develop for other browsers at the same time - again, depending on what your audience will expect.

The fact that it will be cumbersome to test shouldn't be the deciding factor here.  Base your decision on your market's needs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose which browsers you're going to develop for, and have virtual machines (or use services that return images on various machines) for each one you target.

MSIE 8 is no different - you must have a test bed.

As for whether it belongs on your development machine itself should depend on other factors such as whether it helps you develop better, doesn't interfere with your other work/software, and whether you want that to be your 'default' target - ie, what you expect most of your customers to use.

-Adam

Comment: I agree that this is the absolutely correct approach.  However, doesn't it seem silly to need an entire virtual machine just to run a browser?  I wish there were a better (simpler) way.

Comment: @pearcewg — That's a very common sentiment. :-/

Comment: Well, if IE was not integral to windows, and windows integral to IE you might be able to partition them sufficiently on the same system as to be able to use more than one IE on a given install, but unfortunately it's simply not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way right now to have both IE7 and IE8 installed - people have tried to develop tricks like the old MultipleIEs application and they haven't gotten very far to the best of my knowledge.

If you have to capability and time to install and test IE8 on a separate (perhaps virtual) machine then by all means I think you should get in to it now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in my view IE8 in its current state is too buggy to serious explore interop concerns at this point.  You know your audience better than I.  Would at least recommend keeping the potential for creating more problems by attempting to work around any of IE8's many rendering quirks salient in your mind as you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If it were any other browse, I would say: It depends.

You have to remember that many new systems will soon be bundled with IE 8. Also, IE 8 upgrades will become available via Windows Updates.

Given the speed at which IE 7 replaced IE 6 as the most popular version (in roughly 14 months), you should be putting IE 8 into your roadmap, if not immediately adding to developer systems and test plans.